# EF6 lazy loading not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have these objects:

```
public class Domain : EntityTypeConfiguration<Domain>, IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Website> Websites { get; set; }
}

public class Website: EntityTypeConfiguration<Website>, IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int DomainId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LanguageIds { get; set; }

    public bool AllowToSharedTemplates { get; set; }

    public int PublishWebsiteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
}
```

When I want all the websites I want the connected Domains as well (each website has one domain). But somehow this does not work.

```
    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        IList<T> ret;

        using (IocDbContext db = Context.CreateContext())
        {
            DbSet<T> dbSet = db.Set<T>();
            ret = dbSet.ToList();
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The CreateContext

```
    public IocDbContext CreateContext()
    {
        IocDbContext rety=  new IocDbContext(_siteType.ConnectionString);
        rety.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

        return rety;
    }
```

As you can see I have a generic repository. It works fine with just one object, but with navigation properties not. With lazy loading, it does not find the navigation property (domain in this case). I get this error:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.

When I try to map the DTO to an object:

```
public static Objects.Website ToModel(this Data.Contexts.Website value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new Website
        {
            Id = value.Id,
            Name = value.Name,
            Domain = value.Domain?.ToModel()
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have your context wrapped in a `using` statement, lazy loading would never work because by the time you leave the `GetAll()` method, the context has been disposed and the connection to the database has been closed.

As much as lazy loading looks like a great option, I would highly recommend against using it unless you know what you're doing. It's much safer to explicitly load the data you need.

Comment: Okay... As you can see I use the using to initialize the DBContext, using a connectionstring. I use this construction so I can change database at runtime. This is a must. Do you have any idea how I can avoid the using while still being able to change database at runtime?

Comment: The way you create the context is fine the way it is, you just can't dispose of it immediately by putting it inside a `using` block.

Comment: @dropshot32 you can use Include("Domain") instead if you want to dispose context still.